# Proper way to update the value of a variable inside a Python function?

Tags: python, list, function

My following program doesn't modify the original value of the variable `myMatrix`:

```
def transpos(matrixx: list):
    newMatrix = [[matrixx[j][i] for j in range(len(matrixx))] for i in range(len(matrixx[0]))]

    myMatrix = newMatrix

myMatrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
transpos(myMatrix)
print(myMatrix)
```

What is the correct way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the new list and assign it to myMatrix.

```py
def transpos(matrixx: list):
    newMatrix = [[matrixx[j][i] for j in range(len(matrixx))] for i in range(len(matrixx[0]))]
    return newMatrix

myMatrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
myMatrix = transpos(myMatrix)
print(myMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the `global` keyword

One solution is the use of the [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) keyword as below:

```
def transpos(matrixx: list):
    global myMatrix    # <--- 'global' give a reference to myMatrix inside
                       # the function transpos
    newMatrix = [[matrixx[j][i] for j in range(len(matrixx))] for i in range(len(matrixx[0]))]
    myMatrix = newMatrix

myMatrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
transpos(myMatrix)
print(myMatrix)
```